# how to use processing as a library?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, processing

I'm trying to use processing as a normal java library.

The application is working fine, but I can't debug the code because the Visual Studio Code IDE is complaining about missing source files.

[visual studio core missing source file error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DrEL.png)

How can I solve this error?
I would like to debug the processing code properly.

I followed this tutorial in order to import core.jar on my project.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U0TGZCEWn8g

Answer (score 0):

Download the complete [Extension Pack for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack), click the plus sign on the right side of **Referenced Libraaries** under the **JAVA PROJECTS** panel to add a `.jar` package reference.

[image]

Comment: Hi JialeDu, I already did this and it's not working. This is because the core.jar contains only the .class files

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue in the following way, please let me know if you have a better solution.

1. Import the `core.jar` inside your project
2. Processing is compiled with Apache Ant, in order to debug properly you first have to build the `core-sources.jar`, then navigate to the `processing4-processing-1286-4.0.1\core` folder and launch the command `ant source-jar`
3. Copy the `core-sources.jar` inside the project folder
4. Attach the source code from the IDE
5. Now you should be able to see the source code and place breakpoints

I committed the code under the following repo

https://github.com/DanieleCampagnoli/processing-maven-skeleton